# How to validate the billing address information in Django Oscar?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-oscar

How do I collect the billing address information in my Django Oscar Payment details view?
So far I have read the code of Django Oscar in github and in the method handle_place_order_submission() here:https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/05049733e5c6152e37f7b99d957fd67d825c78b8/src/oscar/apps/checkout/views.py#L442 ,the code is:

```
    def handle_place_order_submission(self, request):
        return self.submit(**self.build_submission())
```

they say that I should override this method and then call build_submission.
So I had forked my checkout app and then under PaymentDetailsView(). I wrote a function named build_submission and also imported the BillingAddressForm() , from oscar.apps.payment.forms import BillingAddressForm.

```
    def build_submission(self, **kwargs):
        submission = super(
            PaymentDetailsView, self).build_submission(**kwargs)
        submission['billing_address'] = BillingAddressForm(self.request.POST)
        return submission
```

I have used the {{ billing_address_form }} in my payment_details.html form.The code is here:

```html
<form action="{% url 'checkout:preview' %}" class="form-stacked" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="well">
            <!--<div class="container form-group" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: center">-->
                {{ billing_address_form }}
            <!--</div>-->
        </div>
            <br>
            <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                    data-key="{{ stripe_publishable_key }}" 
                    data-amount="{{ order_total_incl_tax_cents }}"
                    data-name="{{ shop_name }}"
                    data-locale="auto"
                    data-currency="cad"
                    data-description="{{ basket.num_items }} items ({{ order_total.incl_tax|currency }})">
            </script>
    </form>
```

Now how do I validate the billing address form, should I create some separate method?I am new to Oscar so an answer with some code might help me understand better.
Or is there any other way through which I can collect the Billing address from the user?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot validate using `JavaScript` + `google maps services`. Set the submit button of the form to disabled until google maps return that there is a valid address in the address.

In order to ask google for the correctness of the address, you have to put all fragments of such address together, I mean, remember a complete address is composed by several fields of that form like: `line1`, `line2`, `postcode`, `country`, etc ...

**Or ...**

You can validate using `Python` + [Python Client for Google Maps Services](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-python/docs/) in the `clean` method of the form. You have to remember that is form is not valid to set the correct message for the user stating why.

Which page you will redirect to if validation fails is up to you.